# figure with 3X3 subplots having shared x,y axes and labels?

Tags: python, shared, label, axes, subplot

I cannot add create 3x3 subplots with common axes and labels using the following code:

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(24, 12))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)    # The big subplot
    fig.text(0.5, 0.04, 'Time (minutes)', ha='center')
    fig.text(0.04, 0.5, 'Distance travelled (pixels)', va='center', 
   rotation='vertical')
    # Turn off axis lines and ticks of the big subplot
     ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
     ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('none')
     ax.spines['left'].set_color('none')
     ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
     ax.tick_params(labelcolor='w', top='off', bottom='off', 
     left='off', right='off')

     ax1 = fig.add_subplot(331)
     ax1.errorbar(Time, MD11, MD11err, capsize=3, ls='none', 
      color='red', elinewidth=0.5, capthick=1)
      ax1.scatter(Time, S1, s=20, color = 'grey')
      ax1.plot(Time, MD11, color = 'red', label="First 1ug/g 
     injection")
      ax1.plot(Time, S1, color = 'grey', label="Saline")
      ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
      ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
      ax1.title ('MDMA 1 ug/g ')
      ax1.ylabel('First Injection', va='center', rotation='vertical')


       ax2 = fig.add_subplot(332)
       ax2.errorbar(Time, MD31, MD31err, capsize=5, ls='none', 
          color='red', elinewidth=1, capthick=2)
        ax2.errorbar(Time, S4, S4err, capsize=5, ls='none', 
      color='gray', elinewidth=1, capthick=2)
       ax2.scatter(Time, MD31,s=20, color = 'red') 
        ax2.scatter(Time, S4,s=20, color = 'grey')
       ax2.plot(Time, MD31, color = 'red', label="First 3ug/g 
       injection")
       ax2.plot(Time, S4, color = 'grey', label="Saline")
```

and so on till ax9. The above code just created the 331 subplot and not the other ones. I have defined all the variables properly. Please help.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want.  Is there anything in the [Matplotlib Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) that looks like what you need?  Would it be possible to provide a simple code example that demonstrates what you are trying to do - [mcve]

Comment: Something like this: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(6, 6))

fig.text(0.5, 0.04, 'common X', ha='center')
fig.text(0.04, 0.5, 'common Y', va='center', rotation='vertical')